# Copy value every n entries, 0 otherwise in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame, which contains entries I would like to put in a new column in that data frame, every n times and have 0 otherwise in that new column

i.e if my data frame is

```
        col1   col2           number  
        stff1   2012-01-01    14665186 
        stff2  2012-01-01     3782215 
        stff3  2012-01-01     11052835 
        stff1  2012-01-01     6850135 
        stff2  2012-02-01     9746279 
        stff3  2012-02-01     7888386
```

I would like to produce a new column for each "stff#" entry, so the first time producing for instance:

```
        col1   col2           number         newcolstff1
        stff1   2012-01-01    146             146 
        stff2  2012-01-01     378             0
        stff3  2012-01-01     110             0
        stff1  2012-01-01     685             685        
        stff2  2012-02-01     974             0
        stff3  2012-02-01     788             0
```

And then so on with a new column for every stff#

So far I have tried:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataframe[,1])){
ifelse( i=holder[i] ,  dataframe$newcol[holder[i]]<-dataframe[holder[i] , col], dataframe$newcol[i]<-0) }
```

Where holder indicates the indices of what I would like to put in the new column, however this is just repeating the first entry it finds thorughout the length of the data frame.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal in doing this?

Comment: So you want it only for `stff1`? And for rest `0`?

Comment: @SeñorO Going to aggregate by another column once I have achieved this.

Comment: @user1987097  Why the `numbers` got changed in the expected result.

Comment: Did you change the data?

Comment: I changed the numbers to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `model.matrix` do do this for each stff#.

```
dat <- read.table(text="      col1   col2           number  
        stff1   2012-01-01    14665186 
        stff2  2012-01-01     3782215 
        stff3  2012-01-01     11052835 
        stff1  2012-01-01     6850135 
        stff2  2012-02-01     9746279 
        stff3  2012-02-01     7888386 ", header=TRUE)


model.matrix(  ~ 0 + col1 , data=dat) * dat$number
#  col1stff1 col1stff2 col1stff3
#1  14665186         0         0
#2         0   3782215         0
#3         0         0  11052835
#4   6850135         0         0
#5         0   9746279         0
#6         0         0   7888386
```

One way to get the first 3 characters would to then use `substring`

Answer (score 3):

You could either use `acm.disjonctif` from `ade4`

```
  library(ade4)
  cbind(df,acm.disjonctif(df[,1,drop=FALSE])*df$number)
  #  col1       col2   number col1.stff1 col1.stff2 col1.stff3
  #1 stff1 2012-01-01 14665186   14665186          0          0
  #2 stff2 2012-01-01  3782215          0    3782215          0
  #3 stff3 2012-01-01 11052835          0          0   11052835
  #4 stff1 2012-01-01  6850135    6850135          0          0
  #5 stff2 2012-02-01  9746279          0    9746279          0
  #6 stff3 2012-02-01  7888386          0          0    7888386
```

or use `mapply`

```
 un1 <- unique(df$col1)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(mapply(`*`,  with(df, lapply(unique(col1),`==`,
                col1)), list(df$number)))

  colnames(df1) <- paste0("newcol", un1)
  cbind(df,df1)
  #  col1       col2   number newcolstff1 newcolstff2 newcolstff3
  #1 stff1 2012-01-01 14665186    14665186           0           0
  #2 stff2 2012-01-01  3782215           0     3782215           0
  #3 stff3 2012-01-01 11052835           0           0    11052835
  #4 stff1 2012-01-01  6850135     6850135           0           0
  #5 stff2 2012-02-01  9746279           0     9746279           0
  #6 stff3 2012-02-01  7888386           0           0     7888386
```